# Causing underflow in ieee-754 floating point format using subtraction

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy, ieee-754, floating-point-precision, underflow

This seems basic but I am having a lot of trouble answering the following question:

Give two numbers X and Y represented in the IEEE754 format such that computing X-Y will result in underflow.

To my understanding every operation can potentially result in underflow but for the life of mine I cant find an example for subtraction.

PLEASE HELP!!!
thanks

Comment: I assume that this is a homework question so will not provide a direct answer. Under which conditions the magnitude the result of a floating-point subtraction is a lot smaller than the magnitude of the two inputs? What is the magnitude of the smallest floating-point number than can still be represented in normalized fashion in the floating-point format your are looking at? By combining the answers to these two questions you should be able to find an answer to your original question.

Answer (score 4):

When default exception handling is in effect, a subtraction that produces a tiny (in the subnormal interval<sup>1</sup>) non-zero result conceptually causes an underflow exception, but there is no observable effect, because:

- A subtraction that produces a tiny result is necessarily exact, due to characteristics of the floating-point format (there are no significand bits lower than the bits in a subnormal value, and subtraction, unlike multiplication, cannot mathematically have any lower bits than there are in the inputs).
- The IEEE 754-2008 standard says that when there is underflow with default exception handling and the result is exact, no flag (including the underflow flag) is raised. And, since default exception handling is in effect, there is no trap (exceptional change of program control).

For a homework assignment, you may perform a subtraction that has a tiny result and legitimately claim that an underflow exception has occurred, even though no flag is raised and no trap occurred.

To create observable effects of the underflow exception, you would need to change the handling of the underflow exception from the default to something else, such as enabling a trap when an underflow occurs. The means for doing this are language dependent.

---

<sup>1</sup> In the 32-bit binary format, a number is tiny if its magnitude is less than 2<sup>–126</sup>. In the 64-bit format, a number is tiny if its magnitude is less than 2<sup>–1023</sup>. The IEEE 754 standard permits tininess to be determined either before or after the result has been rounded to the normal significand length.

Comment: I understand the concept, my problem is purely theoretical (independent of language).
My problem is that I have to find to numbers in the floating point format. For any two numbers I can think of in floating point format the difference between them is also representable in that format.

Comment: ...I am looking for a concrete example for two numbers in the single precision format that the subtraction between them results in a number smaller in magnitude than 2^-149 (the smallest number by magnitude in single precision format) if anyone can provide one.
Thanks:)

Comment: @mpjunior: the result need not be smaller than the smallest representable positive number; it need only be smaller than the smallest positive *normal* number.

Comment: Thank you stephen! The question makes much more sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

The only possibility I see for getting an underflow on subtraction is to disable denormalized numbers. If you could do that, there would be pairs of distinct doubles whose difference would be too small to represent as a non-zero double.